# WCF Console Application with multiple Service

Tags: web-services, wcf

I have a Console Application that host a WCF service. Right now I configure the application to run in the following way:

```
// within my program class
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // retrieve the current URL configuration
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Uri"]);
```

Then I start a new instance of a WebServiceHost to host my WCF REST service

```
using (WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(MonitorService), baseAddress))
{
    ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (IMonitorService), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
    ServiceDebugBehavior stp = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
    stp.HttpHelpPageEnabled = false;

    host.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
    Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
    Console.ReadLine();

    // Close the ServiceHost.
    host.Close();
}
```

So far so good except that now I came up with the requirement of having two WCF services hosted in the following structure

http://localhost:[port]/MonitorService
and
http://localhost:[port]/ManagementService

Can I add a new service endpoint and distinguish the two endpoints by using a different contract? If yes, the implementation of the two contracts should reside in the same class MonitorService cause it is the one used by the WebServiceHost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can host multiple services in single console application. You can create multiple hosts for multiple services. You can make use of following generic method to start hosts for a given service.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method creates a service host for a given base address and service and interface type
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Service type</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="K">Service contract type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="baseAddress">Base address of WCF service</param>
    private static void StartServiceHost<T,K>(Uri baseAddress) where T:class 
    {
        using (WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(T), baseAddress))
        {
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(K), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
            ServiceDebugBehavior stp = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
            stp.HttpHelpPageEnabled = false;

            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Close the ServiceHost.
            host.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So actually I need to start multiple Service Hosts, one per service and write a mechanism to dispose all together when the Console App is shut-down. Thanks